# deleting multiple photos

Tags: photos

I simply want to delete the bulk if not all of several hundred photos I have uploaded from my camera, to free up space as it is already full.
However I cannot find how to delete them unless I do it one by one which requires at least three different actions and would take forever!
Someone said highlight first and then delete, but I cannot find any control to highlight them!
I went to the nearest Apple shop today. It is 125 kms from where I live. Apparently it does not open until 9.30 am and at 9.10 there are already 30-40 people patently waiting outside!
I do not have time for this, and returned to pay $6 for parking my car!

I SIMPLY WANT TO KNOW HOW TO DELETE GROUPS OF PHOTOS. The photos I want are already transferred to my PC, so even it they are deleted from Cloud it does not matter, but at present when I go travelling I will not be able to download photos as I take them.

Comment: Have you tried the Photos app?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply highlight all files in a folder using `cmd`+`A`. Then you can delete all highlighted files by using `cmd`+`backspace`. You can also highlight multiple files in a folder by clicking the first, then pressing and holding `shift` while clicking the last.